# macOS "USB Accessories Disabled" notification

Tags: imac, usb

My iMac 2015 model is giving me a popup:

[image: USB Accessories Disabled]

> USB Accessories Disabled
>
> Unplug the accessory using too much power to re-enable USB devices.

After which none of the USB ports work.

Obviously I've tried unplugging everything from the USB ports.

I also tried google searching the error.  The advice I found was to unplug the computer overnight, which I did already twice, and I am still getting the error and the USB ports are still not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try not using your USB devices one after another. One might be broken and causing the issue. If the issue persists with only known good devices you might need to take it in for repair.